# Write a biquadratic equation that has as roots the numbers $2$ and $2\sqrt{2}$

Tags: roots

I thought the answer would be: $$(x^2 - 4)(x^2 - 8) = 0$$ 
but it has $4$ roots the positive and negative values. Which is the correct answer?

Comment: Your answer is correct.  Both $2$ and $2\sqrt{2}$ are roots of your equation, which is a [biquadratic](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quartic_function#Biquadratic_equations).  As you observed, they are not the only roots.

Answer (score 1):

If you take *biquadratic* [as a synonym for *quartic*](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/BiquadraticEquation.html) then any of these work:

$$(x-2)^3(x-2\sqrt{2}) \\ (x-2)^2(x-2\sqrt{2})^2 \\ (x-2)(x-2\sqrt{2})^3$$

But otherwise I don't see how to get *only* those two roots in a quartic equation without odd powers (the more common definition of *biquadratic*).

However, as N.F. Taussig points out, what you have is correct, as long as you don't care if there are other roots besides $2$ and $2\sqrt{2}$.  Also, it satisfies the more common definition of what a biquadratic equation is.

Comment: The equations you created are biquadratic or not? As I see you managed to create (biquadratic) equations with only 2 roots.

Comment: It might be biquadratic, but it might not.  I linked to the Wolfram Alpha page in my answer that talks about it.  My definition doesn't matter as much as yours (or your professor's, I assume).  Regardless, it needs to be degree $4$, which means four roots (including multiplicities).  So to get two distinct roots, I have to make one or both multiple roots.

Comment: In my book a before the x^4 should be different from 0 so IN THIS CASE I assume that in this exercise in any solution will be 2 more roots from the ones needed, am I right?

Comment: I edited my answer.